# How to open my application directly by clicking on a link from mail?

Tags: android, deep-copy, deep-linking

I am looking for a solution so far, i.e When user clicks on a link from his mail box My Application should open if My Application is already installed in his device without asking user to choose options with **Just Once** and **Always** .For example, clicking a URI in an email from a bank might result in a dialog asking the user whether to use the browser, or the bank's own app, to open the link, But in my case my application should open directly without asking to choose any option.
I have implemented my application as follows:
My manifest file as **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="http"
                android:pathPrefix="/blog"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My example url is http://www.example.com/blog

I would like to open my application if user clicks on above link.
Please help me with sample code with steps.

Comment: I don't think you can do that . because that depends upon system and system will on open your app if its default otherwise it will show chooser.

Comment: @Arslan uh you can? Click a youtube link from the twitter application and your device will ask you if you want to open the link using Chrome or Youtube.

Comment: So thats a chooser that is asking to open chrome or youtube.

Comment: @Arslan because Android had to open a link to youtube, and now, theres more than 1 application that can open a youtube link, that's why it's asking you to choose. It's not a "chooser that is asking to open chrome or youtube", it's a chooser that's asking which of these programs that can open a youtube link would you like to use because these apps contain a broadcast receiver for a youtube link.

Comment: Wait I didn't see the edit. No, unless the device is rooted, you can't make your application pop up by default without making the user choose first.

Comment: Agree with Razgriz and Arslan - it's not gonna work, unfortunately (unless you have your custom protocol and nothing except of your app can handle it. But then you rely on the fact, that your app is pre-installed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is only available on Android devices running at least Marshmallow (6+) and is referenced as `App Link` throughout the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).

To fully implement this feature, it requires you to own the corresponding url and add a configuration file at this address: `https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`. The file content is described in the documentation (contains the package name and its signature).

Then, modify your intent-filter as follow to enable the `auto-verify` feature:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/blog" />
</intent-filter>
```

You should definitely read the documentation about this feature. It contains a lot of usefuls tips to test your implementation.